# Spanish version of "the tables have turned."

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Is there any Spanish equivalent of the phrase, "the tables have turned," or that communicates a similar message? My Spanish-speaking friend tells me that the literal translation loses the connotation of causing a reversal in one's plans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sentences are similar in Spanish:

- Las tornas han cambiado.
- Ha dado la vuelta a la tortilla.
- Ha dado un giro inesperado.

When a radical change has occurred.

Comment: Another option: **Se han vuelto las tornas** (similar to *Las tornas han cambiado*)

Comment: In Perú we usually say: "Se volteó la torta."

Comment: you can say : "se ha volteado a favor" (have turned foor good), se ha "volteado en contra" (have turned against)

Answer (score 2):

Some other options are:

- Las cosas han cambiado / Las cosas cambiaron
- Las cosas se pusieron de cabeza / La cosa se ha puesto de cabeza
- La situación ha cambiado / La situación cambió
- La situación se invirtió / La situación se ha invertido
- La situación se revirtió / La situación se ha revertido
- La situación dio la vuelta / La situación ha dado la vuelta
- Le salio el tiro por la culata

Comment: Son expresiones un poco extrañas, al menos en castellano.